# Can Berthelot-Ogus be used to prove that varieties do not lift?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

Given a "nice" scheme $X$ over $F_p$, Berthelot-Ogus comparison relates its crystalline cohomology to algebraic de Rham cohomology of its lift to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. The nice thing about crystalline cohomology is that it can be defined even when there is no lift.

Are there any examples when there are purely cohomological obstructions to the existence of a lift, and thus Berthelot-Ogus can be used to show that there is no lift?